# c# addressing a textbox for WRITE on a form from a functional element

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I am trying to get my head around OO and C# and although I have searched I can't see an answer  so, hopefully someone here can help.

I have a form (public Form_DaRT_BOM_Main()) and on it a text box (textBox1). These reside in MSVS2010 generated files.

```
namespace DaRT_BOM
{
  public partial class Form_DaRT_BOM_Main : Form
  {
    public Form_DaRT_BOM_Main()
  }
}
```

I have my own function in Program.cs that resides in

```
public static class GeneralFunctions
{
}
```

I am trying to write text into the textbox but can't see how this should be addressed.

Currently I have:

```
public static String SplitFile(String FileToSplit)
  {
    String line;
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FileToSplit))
    {
      line = reader.ReadLine();
      Form_DaRT_BOM_Main.textBox1 = line;
    }

    return null;
  }
```

Prior to trying to use the textbox for output I was testing using a MessageBox and that worked okay.

What I get now is a compilation error:

An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

Which suggests I am not addressing the textbox correctly.

Please forgive the Mickey Mouse element but I am still trying to understand... old-dog and new tricks syndrome.

Thanks in anticipation.

Steve.

Comment: you don't appear to be addressing the textbox (named `textbox1`) at all.  You go Form.Text

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. Bit of a curve-ball.

If I insert textBox1 there I get:

An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'DaRT_BOM.Form_DaRT_BOM_Main.textBox1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a reference to the form or access textbox1 within the form in some event for example or in the constructor. For example:

```
//inside the form (in an event or constructor).
this.textbox1.Text = GeneralFunctions.SplitFile(some_parameter_here);
```

If you want to access the form from a static class - make it singleton or make some static property which will hold reference to the actual form.

Comment: Pavel, Thanks.

I may need to access this box from several places (function calls). How would that be referenced?

Steve.

Comment: if the functions are inside the form then just access the property (for example `textbox1`. If they are not in the form you may need save a reference to the form where you instantiate it for example `form1 = new MyCoolForm(); form1.textbox1.Text = "Something";`

Comment: Thanks. I need to re-read some stuff I think. this is where I just don't process OO too well.

I understand the concepts of OO (objects, classes, instances etc.) but the implementation just baffles me.

Thanks for your help. :)

Steve.

Comment: Pavel, Thanks. Re-reading made me realise not that I had addressing issues (which I did have) but that the structure of my code was wrong. The text box on this form will only ever need these functions as they are operators on the data for this form. I have moved my functions into the form and now it works fine.

I was trying to work as I would've in C by making reusable code from a 'code operating on data' perspective when really I should have been viewing as 'data requiring these operations'. (I think I have that correct). :)

Steve.